# Qt reading serial input then splitting it into separate variables

Tags: c++, qt, split, serial-port

I'm working on Qt, however I have come across an issue which for the life of me I cant fix at all. I have tried many different combinations to my code, but it still hasn't given me the output I'm looking for. I am hoping someone can help me.

```
 QStringList buffer_split = serialBuffer.split(","); //  split the serialBuffer string, parsing with ',' as the separator

    //  Check to see if there less than 3 tokens in buffer_split.
    //  If there are at least 3 then this means there were 2 commas,
    //  means there is a parsed temperature value as the second token (between 2 commas)
    if(buffer_split.length() < 3){
        // no parsed value yet so continue accumulating bytes from serial in the buffer.
        serialData = arduino->readAll();
        serialBuffer = serialBuffer + QString::fromStdString(serialData.toStdString());
        serialData.clear();
    }else{
        // the second element of buffer_split is parsed correctly, update the temperature value on temp_lcdNumber
        serialBuffer = "";
        qDebug() << buffer_split << "\n";
        parsed_data = buffer_split[1];

}
```

The above solution has worked for me, in turn I am reading the values being sent over the serial port such as:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Above is how `parsed_data` is reading the information from the serial port, which is correct.

The issue I am having, is splitting that, then storing them in separate variables to start some if statements. so far I can't seem to get it to work.

If anyone can help me I would be grateful

Thank You

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. As you have written with parsed_data = buffer_split[1], you can access each individual value and store it. Where are you stuck?

Comment: When i try to store say for example buffer_split[2], it doesnt seem to work. looking for something like this. i hope this makes it a little easier to understand. example the array im sending is 45,0,67,0,0,13, i need each number to be stored in a variable. int num1 = parsed_data[0] which would be 45, int num2 = parsed_data[1] which would be 0 and int num3 = parsed_data[2] which would be 67

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra `parsed_data` variable `buffer_split` stores them, all you  just need `int num1 = buffer_split[0].toInt(); int num2 = buffer_split[1].toInt();` ...

Comment: Hi i did try that before, however the values just stay to zero, even if they change. `num1 = parsed_data.mid(0,1).toInt();` seems to work however i believe this isn't the right way to go around it.

Comment: Hey i m confused a little bit. Can you read original data like 4,0,2,5,7,1 if you cant your problem is reading from serial port not splitting values. Try to send values ends with \n line feed  character  and read it when whole line received you can check with canReadLine() function